# How to get values from a button

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form which goes through three steps. In step 2, I am asking the user to select a speciality by clicking the corresponding button. If they click a button, they should move to the 3<sup>rd</sup> and final step.

Here is the button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional "
        type="button" name="hair_stylist" >HAIR STYLIST</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional " 
        type="button" name="cosmetologist" >COSMETOLOGIST</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional " 
        type="button" name="makeup_artist" >MAKEUP ARTIST</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional " 
        type="button" name="barber" >BARBER</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional " 
        type="button" name="esthetician" >ESTHETICIAN</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional " 
        type="button" name="nail_technitian" >NAIL TECHNITIAN</button>
```

I don't think name will work here. Is there anything that can be done with `data-*`? How can I send and grab this value in PHP when the form is submitted?

Comment: There isn't any back tab key... You can use the editor and click on "tidy code"

Comment: maybe a hidden input updated properly?

Comment: `button` has a `value` attribute, too.

Comment: Hmm, how to make the hidden input associated with right button ?? @mic4ael

Comment: Why don't you use `<select />`?

Comment: Hi, @Ivan , could you please also tell me how to back tab in note pad plus plus ??

Comment: Select won't create such a view that I am looking for..

Comment: Avoid WRITING IN ALL CAPS in HTML. Many screen readers will take it as an initialism and spell it out letter by letter. You can [use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) to display things in uppercase without that drawback.

Comment: Back Tab = `Shift Tab`

Comment: Shift Tab simply delete the my codes :( tried that before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a name is fine and necessary.

There are two problems.

1. You need actually have a value in order to send a value
2. You need the button to be a submit button in order to submit the form

Such:

```
<button 
    class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional"
    type="submit" 
    name="profession"
    value="hair_stylist">
        Hair Stylist 
</button>
```

Then in PHP you can simply:

```
do_something_with($_POST["profession"]);
```

Comment: But they form consists of other input so there will be one submit button which will send all the values of all the fields including buttons' values !

Comment: @HkmSadekHossain — Incorrect. A submit button is only a successful control (i.e. will only send it's name and value when the form is submitted) if it is the button used to trigger the form. (Except possibly in some *very old* and unsupported versions of Internet Explorer which were notoriously buggy when it came to button elements).

Comment: May be I am not clear. Or I am not getting you, By the way, how can submit the forms with all the name using one "Send" button which is a submit type?

Comment: @HkmSadekHossain — In the question you said "If they click a button, they should move to the 3rd and final step." If you've changed your mind and you want to pick a profession and then click a separate submit button: Use radio buttons for the profession.

Comment: Thank you... I think I have got what to do.. Thanks again... please let me know if there is any other options I can use

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jquery Post function for this.
First little bit change your html code. Put your values inside `id` of your buttons

```
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional "
type="button" name="hair_stylist" id="HAIR STYLIST">HAIR STYLIST</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional "
type="button" name="cosmetologist" id="COSMETOLOGIST">COSMETOLOGIST</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional "
type="button" name="makeup_artist" id="MAKEUP ARTIST">MAKEUP ARTIST</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional "
type="button" name="barber" id="BARBER" >BARBER</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional "
type="button" name="esthetician" id="ESTHETICIAN" >ESTHETICIAN</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional "
type="button" name="nail_technitian" id="NAIL TECHNITIAN" >NAIL TECHNITIAN</button>
```

Then Some jquery code here:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nextBtn').on('click', function () {



        $.post("NewPage.php",
            {value: this.id
        });
    });
 });
```

After clicking button. That particular button will be accessed by its class then it sends data to `NewPage.php` (You have to make new php page) where you can access value by POST array.
**NewPage.php**

```
If(isset($_POST['value']))
{
  //Do your process here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `value` parm.

Example:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-proffessional " type="button" name="hair_stylist" value="HAIR STYLIST">HAIR STYLIST</button>
```